# Mocking of Object

Tags: .net, mocking

How i can set expectation on _somerepository.SaveOrUpdate(Object) in nhibernet in .net .

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Moq framework you could do similar to...

```
Mock<IDataAccessObject> mockDataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccessObject>();

// Setting up the mock to return expected values as part of the tests
mockDataAccess.Setup(dal => dal.SaveOrUpdate(Object)).Returns(expectedReturnValue);

// Calling the receiver business layer passing in the mocked DataAccess
using (BusinessLayerObject bl = new BusinessLayerObject(mockDataAccess.Object))
{
    result = bl.SaveOrUpdate(Object);
}
```